# JVM crashes with SIGSEGV in libpq.so

Tags: postgresql, crash, jvm, libpq

JVM crashes unexpectedly from time to time in our servers with SIGSEGV. We are using JNI to call some C functions which eventually use ECPG to talk to postgres db.

Here is a stack trace for reference:

```
Stack: [0xa895e000,0xa89af000],  sp=0xa89ab550,  free space=309k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libpq.so.5+0x1a42c]  resetPQExpBuffer+0x2c
C  [libpq.so.5+0x1a46f]  printfPQExpBuffer+0x1f
C  [libpq.so.5+0x10b1a]  PQgetResult+0xea
C  [libpq.so.5+0x10c97]
C  [libpq.so.5+0x110e7]  PQexec+0x27
C  [libecpg.so.6+0x506f]  ECPGdo+0xc5f
C  [libvcswsilib.so+0x9b914]  get_codes_info+0x4eb
C  [libvcswsilib.so+0x4b4c8]  getCodes(CConference*, CUser const&)+0xc8
C  [libvcswsilib.so+0x4d06d]  CConf::GetFromDatabase(CUser const&, std::string const&)+0x203
C  [libvcswsilib.so+0x4ce0f]      CConf::GetFromDatabaseViaEitherCode(CUser const&, std::string const&)+0xd7
C  [libvcswsilib.so+0x3acac]  getCommon(CUser&, std::string const&, std::string&)+0x45
C  [libvcswsilib.so+0x3b56e]  getCred(std::string const&, std::string&)+0x107
C  [libvcswsilib.so+0x376fa]  WebServiceImpl_getCredJNI+0x78
j   WebServiceImpl.getCredJNI(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+0
j   WebServiceImpl.getInfo(Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;Lcom/Lis tener;Ljava/util/HashMap;)Ljava/lang/String;+51
j  MessageProcessor.processInfo(Lcom/wss/MessageProcessor$MessagePacket;)V+47
j  MessageProcessor.processMessage(Lcom/wss/Manager$MessagePacket;Ljava/lang/String;)V+79
J 388% C2 Manager.run()V (257 bytes) @ 0xf4737b9c [0xf47370c0+0xadc]
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x459d54]
V  [libjvm.so+0x61b129]
V  [libjvm.so+0x45923a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x45936b]
V  [libjvm.so+0x4a4ffc]
V  [libjvm.so+0x73b040]
V  [libjvm.so+0x73b339]
V  [libjvm.so+0x622689]
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x6b39]  start_thread+0xc9
```

We have scanned through the native and Java code and didn't find anything which might be leading to this issue. Don't have much idea on the working of ECPG or postgres.

Any kind of help/idea for debugging the issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: look at where your libpq/libecpg/libvcswsilib builds come from, file a bug/support ticket with the devs?